# Generate an 'Interface' from an existing class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a class as:

```
Class MyClass
{
   public MyClass { ... }
   public string Name { get { ... } }
   public int IdNumber { get { ... } set { ... } }
   public void GenerateNme {...}
}
```

It is just a sample class. I wish to generate an *Interface* from it. Like, MyClass is implementing the IMyClass interface. I wish the output to be

```
public Interface IMyClass
{
   string Name { get; }

   int IdNumber { get; set; }

   void GenerateNumber();
}
```

and

```
MyClass : IMyClass
{

}
```

It can be done manually, but I was just curious to know, is there another simple method to follow to accomplish this?

Comment: Only by inspection: The syntax highlighter doesn't seem to like the first and the last part. Shouldn't it be "`class`" (lower case) and some kind of qualifier before "`MyClass`", respectively? Or is the syntax highlighter just weird? Or is the last part actually correct?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Yes, you can extract an interface from a class using Visual Studio:

Inside the target class file: **Right Click** > **Refactor** > **Extract Interface...**

**Example**

[image]

then

[image]

Comment: As far as I've been able to find out, this is not possible for **VB.NET** in any version of Visual Studio prior to VS 2015 when it was added.

Comment: One other thing that had me confused (seems obvious now) - the class you are extracting an interface for needs at least one public method...  I had to change all internal methods to public.

Comment: Refactor isn't available in VS2017

Comment: I don't have the right click > menu item in VS2017, but I can click on the class name in code and the shortcut "CTRL+R, I" still works.

Comment: in VS2017 click on the class name in code, right click, select 'Quick actions and refactorings',  select 'Extract Interface'

Comment: in  (VS 2019)  : unfortunately this works only for first time. Once you generate the interface and add few new methods in class , then  you can not automatically add this new methods via some options , even if you delete the interface & its .cs file again and try to create new inteface , but somehow visual studio keeps generating blank inteface , looks like it saved this infor somewhere that iterface has been created once earlier.

Answer (score 60):

In Visual Studio 2015/2017/2019/2022, this is under the Quick Actions menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ period <kbd>.</kbd>)

Be sure to put the cursor somewhere in the class name you want to extract the interface from. Otherwise it shows "no quick actions available here".

Note: this is only possible if you can actually extract an interface. For example if your class only has static methods this will not work.

Comment: Strange, my class does not have any static members at all but I still cannot extract it.

Comment: Thank you! I've been struggling with this for months! I can get to the Interface UI, but when I click OK, nothing has happened. Having the cursor on the class name did the trick for me.

Answer (score 14):

In Visual Studio 2010, you can right-click `MyClass` and choose `Refactor`, `Extract Interface..." (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>). This gives you a window to check the members to be extracted.

Answer (score 11):

In the latest versions of Visual Studio (2019 & 2022) the menu item has been renamed from the accepted answer. The complete list of how to now get to the interface popup is as follows (only the first listed has changed from earlier versions):

- Right click on the name of the class and select the **Quick Actions
  and Refactorings...** menu option (not Refactor as in earlier versions). Another menu will then appear, select **Extract interface...**.

  [image: Quick Actions and Refactorings popup menu]
- Have the cursor in the name of the class and then hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>.</kbd> then select the **Extract interface...** menu option.

  [image: Extract interface popup menu]
- Go to the **Edit** menu item then **Refactor** and **Extract Interface** (you do not need to have the class name selected for this, the operation will be performed on the class you have open)

  [image: Extract interface full menu]
- Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then press <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>I</kbd> in close succession (again the operation will be performed on the class you have open)

Performing any of the four above actions will bring up the **Extract Interface** window (this is largely unchanged from earlier versions, although you can choose to add the interface to your current file)

[image: Extract Interface window]

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio 2015, click cursor in or right click on the class name, then select Quick Actions (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>) and the 'Extract Interface' option shows.

Comment: Cool edit @Stijn, I'll have to remember that: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Please take note. If your class has a `static` in it you won't be able to extract to interface, so remove that first before you extract to interface

Comment: To clarify on the above static methods won't be extracted but any non static methods will be.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Refactor* menu of Visual Studio, there is an "extract interface" option that does exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> was popping up 'generating overrides...' and nothing was happening beyond that so I searched 'refactor' in the quick launch search box. Results had `Edit -> Refactor -> Extract Interface` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) option.

Hoping, this tip can help someone else too. I am using VS 2017 EE.